# Resume Download support for MSDN subscription

Tags: download, msdn

I have subscribed for `MSDN Ultimate subscription` recently. The problem is when I try to download any large software from there (Such as VS 2013 Ultimate), it takes a lot of time and it doesn't support resume feature. It keeps on restarting the download even if the internet gets timesout for few minutes. Internet is really unreliable at my place and I can't expect it to work for 12 hours continuously.

I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/703596e0-ed0e-4f53-a063-7378314a9e73/why-msdn-subscription-does-not-support-download-resume-capability?forum=msdnfeedback) that MSDN download are supported by using either `Akamai Download Manager` or `Microsoft File Transfer Manager`. But I can't find a way to install either of them, even with using IE. I downloaded MSFTM already, but it doesn't connect with IE when downloading anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer failing to download using File Transfer Manager can happen if you're using Windows 8 and Internet Explorer 11.  Microsoft describes a workaround for that issue here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2900662/

To work around this issue, try to download the file in Internet Explorer 9 mode. To do this, follow these steps:1.In Internet Explorer, open the MSDN Subscriptions download page.
2.In the Search box, search for the product that you want to download.
3.Open the Developer Tools pane. To do this, press F12.
4.Open the Emulation screen. To do this, press Ctrl+8.
5.On the Document mode list under Mode, click 9.
6.On the User agent string list under Mode, click Internet Explorer 9.

Note After you change the user agent string setting, the download page reloads in Internet Explorer 9 mode.
7.Try again to download the product. The File Transfer Manager application or another download manager should open.
8.After the download begins, close the Developer Tools pane. To do this, press F12 or click the Close button in the upper-right corner of the pane.
Note After the download begins, you can close the Developer Tools pane without interrupting the download progress. The browser remains in Internet Explorer 9 mode until you close this pane.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.